# Get all class names of certain CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

Given a CSS attribute, e.g.

```css
color: #fff;
```

how would I find all class names where this attribute is being applied?

For example,

```css
.hello {
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
}
.world {
    color: pink;
    background: teal;
}
.white,
.classname {
    color: #fff;
}
```

would return `.hello`, `.white` and `.classname` as they all have the attribute `color: #fff`.

Comment: What is the use case for this, if I might ask?  This feels really strange that you are trying to write logic to test your CSS rules, when you should be aware of what your rules do already.  It really feels like a potential XY problem.

Comment: Does this have to be done in javascript? I would use a bash script to accomplish this. `grep -nr '#fff' .`

Comment: I'm color blind and I often need to rewrite css of certain web pages, just trying to see if there's more pragmatic ways to go about it as I'm very new to code :)

Comment: @JosephCho doesn't have to be js, but I have no experience in bash but I'm willing to learn :)

Comment: Use CSS variables when declaring colours, and that way you only have to update the variable in one place instead of tracking down all of the instances.

Comment: So really your question isn't how to check what CSS rule makes an element a color, but just how to find which elements are a color.  No matter if that is because of a css rule, or inline styling.

Comment: @delinear I'm not the one writing the initial css code :)

Comment: I'm assuming this will be apart of some user script that you will be using to modify existing webpages you visit?

Comment: @Taplar doesn't have to be just looking for the most basic answer to the problem I'm trying to solve then will expand upon it myself

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your actual question is.  Your question needs to be concrete and not expanding.  If there are details you have left out of the question, such as if this is going to be a user script for existing webpages you visit, that information needs to be included in the question so people are aware of what the situation is.

Comment: Ctrl + F to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the styleSheets, and then traverse the rules..

Here is an example..

It also includes a little utility function to convert the color, because inside the stylesheet #fff will be rgb(255, 255, 255)..

```js
function realColor (name) {
  const d = document.createElement("div");
  d.style.color = name;
  d.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  const ret = window.getComputedStyle(d).color;
  d.remove();
  return ret;
}

const findcolor = realColor("#fff");

console.log("What selectors have a color of #fff?");
for (const s of document.styleSheets) {
  for (const r of s.cssRules) {
    if (r.style && r.style.color) {
      if (r.style.color === findcolor) {
        console.log(r.selectorText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hello {
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
}
.world {
    color: pink;
    background: teal;
}
.white,
.classname {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="hello">hello</span>
<span class="world">world</span>
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `document.styleSheets.cssRules`, that's much better than my approach of iterating over the DOM elements instead.  Kudos for your `realColor()` function too