# javascript run as last script after page loaded

Tags: javascript, onload-event

I was wondering if it's possible to edit the content of an embedded js which runs and generates dom content. Like for example fb js comments code or analytics code.

Is it possible to run a function as the last function that runs on the site so I can be able to make a modification of the rendered content that the embedded script generated. Let's take an example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = \'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2\';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>
```

When this code renders it generates a comments box, that looks as follows:
[image]

IS it possible to run a script after the content has been generated. And lets say modify a span element in the generated output?

Edit: I'M NOT INTERESTED IN CSS SOLUTIONS. I KNOW CSS, I ASKED SPECIFICALLY ABOUT JAVASCRIPT. NOT CSS

Comment: Why are you looking to do that?

Comment: For customization needs. Is it even possible, or I should not bother even trying

Comment: Well you could open the console, see the corresponding classes and try to change them to see if it works. What's wrong with that?

Comment: One idea is too alter the CSS for Facebook once the stylesheet is loaded.   Here is an example I made for querying the stylesheets, but it's also possible to alter them too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139575/get-all-class-names-of-certain-css-attributes/51140136#

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you can work out what className or CSS selector for the parts of the Facebook you want to change.  You can directly change the stylesheet for these.

Below is a little snippet that demonstrates this.  If we pretend the classname `.test` is some CSS selector on this Facebook plugin, you could change the color like below.  The setInterval is of course not needed, it's only there to show that it's changing in real time.

```js
let cssEntry;

for (const s of document.styleSheets) {
  for (const r of s.cssRules)  {
    if (r.selectorText === ".test") {
      cssEntry = r;
    }
  }
}

let c = 0;
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

setInterval(() => {
  cssEntry.style["background-color"] = colors[(c++)%3];
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>This should be white text on black background<p>
  <p>But in a few seconds should change between red / green / blue every second by directly changing the CSS inside the loaded stylesheet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @inrob  This is a Javascript solution.   Above there are 15 lines of Javascript.  The CSS is only included as an example to make sense of the Snippet.  You didn't really say what modification your after, if it's just colors etc, then the above will work nicely.  If it's the HTML, there is another way to do that too, but to be fair, with me getting a downvote, and the tone of your response, I have no interest in helping you anymore.

Comment: sorry I confused your answer with another one

Comment: Ok, we all have them days..   :)  Looking at your other posts, I can see this is not what your like normally.  Just a bad day at the office. ?

Comment: It might sound strange. But I  think I'm at the end of my biological cycle  here on earth. My system might turn off :\

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use css to do that? `!important` can help in these situations...

If not, you could use the [jQuery Live Query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) but i think it is a bit outdated...

```
$('.theElementSelector').livequery(function() {
  //your code to change appearance of controls
});
```

Or you could use `DOMNodeInserted` (which is also outdated/deprecated):

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.theElementSelector', function(e) {
  //your code to change appearance of controls
});
```

A better solution is to use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Another is [insertionQuery](https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery):

```
insertionQ('theElementSelector').every(function(element){
    //callback
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use css. About the insertionQuery, should  I specify a div that is entered? What If I dodnt know the div class/id? Can't I put a global listener? Or I put body as the selected element? insertionQ('body') ?

Comment: I want to use plain javascript is it possible? Or just jquery?

Comment: look in developer tools and see what is the best way to select the new element...

Comment: are you available for hire for this task? PM ME

Comment: @inrob - PM on StackOverflow are not supported. Find me online if you want although I can see you have marked Keith post as the answer, so probably don't need me anymore... Good luck!